# Библиотека для текста android

Tags: android, текст, library

Доброго времени суток.

По одному стечению обстоятельств, пришлось написать некую программу, парсящую статьи из интернета и выделяющие в них ключевые слова (Основную мысль, если хотите), для последующего использования ключевиков в качестве тэгов. Внимание, вопрос, дорогие знатоки. Существует ли под андроид библиотека, которая сама из обычного текста выделяет каким-либо образом ключевые слова? Просто я даже не представляю, как возможно все это написать самому.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: может нужна библиотека морфологии для русского языка (чтобы получить "нормальную" форму всех слов), потом частотный анализ ?

Comment: @Dmitry Ponyatov Да, спасибо, возможно воспользую вашим советом, но дело в том, что частота использования слова не всегда коррелирует со значимостью этого слова. В тексте про рекламу, например, это слово может ни разу не употребляться, но единственный ли это вариант выхода из положения? Спасибо за ответ, кстати)

Comment: то есть задача из области ИИ: распознавание естественного языка, да еще и на русском ? вроде есть вариант применения семантических сетей, но (а) исходный текст должен иметь разметку и (б) задача распознавания смысла текста компьютером 8-)

Comment: А как работают поиски ключевых фраз, скажем, для SEO?

Comment: Вопрос в том, существует ли библиотека с данным функционалом?

Comment: cкорее всего она ДСПшная, и называется core.yandex.com , не разу не слышал что под андроид есть какие-то локальные поисковые приложения, типа сборки Архивариус2000

Answer (score 2):

Скорее надо искать "как работает морфологическая индексация в поисковых машинах": первые попавшиеся

со ссылками на литературу: http://www.colta.ru/articles/specials/4070

http://www.cwpro.ru/study/website-promotion-search-engine/how-does-the-search-engine-index.html

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите в сторону библитеки Python NLTK, можно начать вот с этих статей:

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-pythonnltk/
- pymorphy https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/176575/
- курс Введение в обработку естественного языка http://kansas.ru/nlp2016/

Алгоритм Яндекс Палех
https://m.habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/314222/